# How to hide all code snippets at once in R markdown Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

How can I press the little hide button for all code snippets at once?  When I run code, it opens and unhides the code snippets, but they are annoying and make the document too long.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but you might want to look at [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections). You might even find other things there. But the short answer is:

```
Edit
 -> Folding:
     -> Collapse All — Alt+O
     -> Expand All — Shift+Alt+O
```

Comment: Any way to have this just include code part, not the sections in the latex writeup part?

Comment: Not that I know of.